# go run -race showing DATA RACE even when code is under a lock

Tags: go, concurrency, race-condition

Quite possible that I missing something basic but from what I understood the below should not have DATA RACE.

Consider below as some_file.go

```
type Key struct {
}
type Val struct {
}

type Tmp struct {
    smMap map[Key]Val
    lock sync.RWMutex
}

func (t *Tmp) setMap(k Key, v Val) {
    t.lock.Lock()
    t.smMap[k] = v // line#13
    t.lock.Unlock()
}

func (t *Tmp) deleteFromMap(k Key) {
    t.lock.Lock()
    delete(t.smMap, k) // line#19
    t.lock.Unlock()
}

func (t *Tmp) getMap(k Key) {
    t.lock.Lock()
    defer t.lock.Unlock()
    return t.smMap[k]
}
```

But the logs on the stdout say that there is DATA RACE:

```
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c0004cc990 by main goroutine:
  runtime.mapassign()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:578 +0x0
  some_file.go:13 +0x70

Previous write at 0x00c0004cc990 by goroutine 925:
  runtime.mapdelete()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:695 +0x0
  some_file.go:19

Goroutine 925 (running) created at:
```

Can someone tell if I am missing something?

I attempted using defer as well and still the same DATA RACE result.

Comment: Provide the main code. Do you have other read and write operations on `smMap` other than via `setMap` and `deleteFromMap`.

Comment: There is one other get operation but since the go race tool output is showing race between just these two, I provided only those 2 methods. I'll add the 3rd one as wel.

Comment: Based on your use of `sync.RWMutex`, it is better to use `RLock` and `RUnlock` for `getMap`. There is no error from these three methods, so please provide how you use `Tmp`.

Comment: Thanks @Trock, I'll do that. WRT the usage of Tmp, it is only being accessed by these 3 methods and no one else is updating it. If rest of the code snippet is still needed then let me know and I'll do it, I'll have to sanitize the code to be able to share it here.

While I do that though, would it really matter how the Tmp struct is being used, especially given the go race detector tool explicitly tells where the contention is? asking to understand if I am missing something.

Comment: Because the code you gave is correct [test](https://go.dev/play/p/RMp7Fejv2Mb). So there can only be something missing somewhere. Or use `sync.Map` to check [test-by-sync-map](https://go.dev/play/p/PyhyV-GvLE6).

Comment: Thanks for testing and sharing that. I had tried a similar go func and for loop and sleep approach but didn't find anything.

"So there can only be something missing somewhere" - this is something I am trying to understand more. Say there is a bug in the code elsewhere, say something is not being accessed correctly. If that would have been the case then wouldn't the go run race tool highlight it?
Let's say it didn't catch any race there; what the tool is showing for a fact is there is a race at above location, so irrespective of the bug elsewhere something needs to be fixed above, isn't it?

Comment: In any case, I also realize that the sanitization I have done above could be causing to misrepresent what I am trying to show. Let me think of a better way to present my code in as close to what I am seeing as possible. Meanwhile, if something strikes then please feel free to share that.

Comment: Run `go vet` on your code. The most likely mistake with the code shown here is that you copied the `Tmp` value.

Comment: @JimB you are absolutely right. Somewhere in the code the Tmp value was getting copied and hence the locks were getting copied. I had run a go vet ./... command from the parent dir but this didn't get flagged. The lock is embedded in a struct which is embedded in a struct and that is what is being returned. I would have expected that to be highlighted but go vet returns nothing.

Comment: To tell with an example what I am trying to say take a look at https://go.dev/play/p/SQ5X8n5wqEj. When you run the program, the address values that are printed are different, which means a copy is being made (if I have got my facts and understanding right about go so far). Feel free to point out any mistakes in my understanding. To me, this looks like a case wherein the address is returned but is dereferenced and a copy is stored which is not being detected by go vet (I could be wrong here but that is what I think).